# Configure RequireJS modules to return only when initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I'm using RequireJS to structure my current JS project and I have some libraries/jQuery plugins that need to be initialized before they can be used. The initializing is async and on return will invoke a callback. The following code hence introduces race conditions (is the dependency loaded **and** initialized?):

dep_that_needs_to_be_initialized_before_it_can_be_used.js:

```
define(
    ['raw_library_source'],
    function(){
        // this init call is async and will invoke the callback when done
        // $ is global
        $.plugin.init({
            //config
        },callback);
    }
);
```

app.js:

```
define(
    ['dep_that_needs_to_be_initialized_before_it_can_be_used'],
    function(){
        // the following line may fail in case the dependcy is not yet initialzed
        $.plugin.doSomething();
    }
);
```

Does anyone know how I could make the require of the dependency 'wait' (aka make it synchronously) until it the library is also initialized?

Answer (score 2):

The way I typically do these is return a wrapper function from a plugin wrapper module and then call the returned wrapper function with a callback.  Couple that with a flag in the module's closure to indicate whether the plugin has already been initialized, and I think you have a solution.

Example:

```
//pluginWrapper.js
define(
  ['jquery', 'plugins/jquery.plugin'],
  function($) {
    var isInitialized = false;
    return function (callback) {
      if (isInitialized) {
        callback();
      } else {
        $.plugin.init({}, function() {
          isInitialized = true;
          callback();
        });
      }
    };
  }
);
```

Then, in any module that you want to use your plugin in, you could:

```
define( ['jquery', 'pluginWrapper'],
  function($, pluginWrapper) {
    pluginWrapper(function() {
      // use the plugin here.  it will be initialized.
    }
  }
);
```

AMD Modules and javascript closures are great, but both can be a bit confusing when you're just getting the hang of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, interesting approach, I'll have a go with it!